# tmux script with quotes

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm using a tmux script in bash that has the following code:

```
tmux send-keys -t d4 'tmux send-keys -t "server1 tail -F /var/log/file.log | grep --line-buffered keyword | egrep --line-buffered "Two keywords" | /root/another_app" ENTER' ENTER
```

When the line is passed to tmux, `"Two keywords"` is transformed in `Twokeywords`.

I've tried to escape the quotes to no avail.

The same is happening to a more complex line, which is:

```
tmux send-keys -t d4 'tmux send-keys -t server2 "tail -F /var/log/file2.json | grep --line-buffered -a '"event_type":"keyword"' | /root/another_app" ENTER' ENTER
```

Also no luck in escaping the quotes.

My objective is to have the first line be sent to tmux as:

```
tail -F /var/log/file.log | grep --line-buffered keyword | egrep --line-buffered "Two keywords"
```

and the second line as

```
tail -F /var/log/file2.json | grep --line-buffered -a '"event_type":"keyword"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this:

```
tmux send-keys -t d4 'tmux send-keys -t "server1 tail -F /var/log/file.log | grep --line-buffered keyword | egrep --line-buffered '"'Two keywords'"' | /root/another_app" ENTER' ENTER
```

because:

```
echo 'tmux send-keys -t "server1 tail -F /var/log/file.log | grep --line-buffered keyword | egrep --line-buffered '"'Two keywords'"' | /root/another_app" ENTER'
tmux send-keys -t "server1 tail -F /var/log/file.log | grep --line-buffered keyword | egrep --line-buffered 'Two keywords' | /root/another_app" ENTER
```

Are sure with two ENTER at the end?

For the second one you might use a here document to assign your special tmux parameter to a variable and then call your tmux with this variable:

```
var=$(cat <<SETVAR
'tmux send-keys -t server2 "tail -F /var/log/file2.json | grep --line-buffered -a '"event_type":"keyword"' | /root/another_app" ENTER'
SETVAR
)
echo "$var"
'tmux send-keys -t server2 "tail -F /var/log/file2.json | grep --line-buffered -a '"event_type":"keyword"' | /root/another_app" ENTER'
```

so try then

```
var=$(cat <<SETVAR
'tmux send-keys -t server2 "tail -F /var/log/file2.json | grep --line-buffered -a '"event_type":"keyword"' | /root/another_app" ENTER'
SETVAR
)
tmux send-keys -t d4 "$var" ENTER
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Any recommendations on how to fix in a similar fashion the second line. I noticed, however, that the solution replaced the quotes to 'Two keywords' instead of "Two keywords". The second line is more picky and requires the usage of " instead of '.

Comment: You should think about where a string starts and where it ends. If you use to much different " and ' characters, it might be easier to use heredocs. I will edit my solution.

Comment: True, worth looking into. I also edited the question, as the second line needs to be '"event_type":"keyword"', which complicates things even further.

Comment: i have edit my solution, but i have no plan if your tmux will run with it. Good luck!

Comment: Please don't recommend the ABS as a documentation source -- it frequently showcases bad practices in its examples, and needing to teach people to unlearn things they picked up there is a constant source of frustration to the freenode #bash IRC channel. Much better to point people at [the official bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents), or [the bash-hackers' wiki](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#here_documents), or [the Wooledge wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument).

Comment: It got pretty close, but unfortunately I can't seem to be able to pass '"event_type":"keyword"' no matter how I quote it. With your example it removed the quotes.

Comment: I'm now able to get, sent to tmux, the following: ''event_type':'alert'' (they are all single quotes). This is done with ''"event_type"':'"alert"'' in Oliver variable example. If there was a way to replace it so that '"event_type":"alert"' (replace single with double quotes) that would fix the problem in tmux.

Comment: Espacing \" fixed it so that I could send it tmux with " as needed. @OliverGaida just \" on your answer will do the trick. Such as: '\"event_type\":\"keyword\"'

Comment: Nice, so my answer lead you to the final solution.